# What is the spectrum of the continuous extension of a bounded operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $H_{0}$ is a dense subspace in $H.$

Giving a bounded operator $A_{0}:H_{0}\rightarrow H_{0}$ with $\sigma \left(
A_{0}\right) $ as spectrum, what would be $\sigma \left( A\right) $, if $A$
is the continuous extension of $A_{0}$ to $H$ ?

Thank you !